# How to import current lodash/fp to Deno?

Tags: typescript, lodash, deno

What I tried:

```
import {debounce} from 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.15-es/lodash.js';
```

Found this in other answer, but it isn't `/fp` and not available in current version.

```
import {debounce} from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash/fp?dts';
```

This results in 3392 errors, usually `[ERROR]: Cannot find namespace 'lodash'.`.

---

How to (easily) import current version of `lodash/fp` in Deno?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use Skypack since they are partnered with Deno, then I would import all packages from their CDN:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/server.ts";
import lodash from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash";
import fp from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash/fp";
import debounce from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash/fp/debounce";

const s = serve({ port: 8080 });

console.log("http://localhost:8080/");
console.log("fp", fp);
console.log("lodash", lodash);
console.log("debounce", debounce);

for await (const req of s) {
  req.respond({ body: "Welcome to Deno!\n" });
}
```

**[DEMO here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sammet-pbk1y?file=/src/index.ts:0-381)** (make some irrelevant change in `index.ts` and save the file, Codesandbox should restart the server and console.log the `debounce` object)

Or simply import the `debounce` function from `lodash`, not `lodash/fp`:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/server.ts";
import { debounce } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash";

const s = serve({ port: 8080 });

console.log("http://localhost:8080/");
console.log("debounce", debounce);

for await (const req of s) {
  req.respond({ body: "Welcome to Deno!\n" });
}
```

Comment: Types don't seem to work. With `import lodash from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash";
import {debounce} from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash/fp';` I am getting `error: TS2614 [ERROR]: Module '"https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash/fp"' has no exported member 'debounce'.`

Comment: @menfon I have updated the answer to include `debounce` as well

Comment: Well, that works. But I am commonly importing dozen or more functions from `lodash/fp`. With your approach that would mean dozen or more import statements, one for every function. I don't consider that easy. I also suspect IDE won't suggest imports of other currently not imported `lodash/fp` functions.

Comment: If that is the case, can't you simply import the whole lodash and extraxt the debounce function from it? See the updated answer.

Comment: @menfon I think you have been trying to get that function from the invalid resource. If you visit https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/fp/debounce.js you can see it's importing https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/debounce.js which is the same code presented in https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js

Comment: Generally functions from `lodash` and `lodash/fp` are *not* the same. `lodash/fp` has curried functions and arguments are usually rearranged to logically make sense with partial application. In NodeJS or browser environment (webpack), you can import from `lodash/fp` and I am asking, how to do it in Deno.